# Android: onDestroy not executed after calling stopSelf

Tags: android, qt, service, ondestroy

I have a QtAndroid application with a service implemented using QtService. If I want to quit the service, I do it like this:

**In C++:**

```
QtAndroid::androidService().callMethod<void>("quit");
```

**In Java service:**

```
public void quit() {
    stopSelf();
}
```

Then there is an onDestroy function:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.d("MyService", "Called onDestroy");
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

The log message is never shown and I suppose the onDestroy function gets not called. In my application the service is not even stopped. I tried a minimal example based on [this guide](https://www.kdab.com/qt-android-create-android-service-using-qt/). With this minimal implementation the service is stopped but the onDestroy function is not called neither.

To demonstrate the problem I took the example source code and modified it like this:

**server.cpp**

```
#include <QAndroidService>
#include <QtAndroid>
#include "rep_pingpong_source.h"

class PingPong : public PingPongSource {
public slots:
    // PingPongSource interface
    void ping(const QString &msg) override {
        qDebug() << "KDAB: Message "+msg;
        emit pong(msg + " from server");
        if (msg == "Quit") {
            qDebug() << "MyService: C++ quit";
            QtAndroid::androidService().callMethod<void>("quit");
        }
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QAndroidService app(argc, argv);

    QRemoteObjectHost srcNode(QUrl(QStringLiteral("local:replica")));
    PingPong pingPongServer;
    srcNode.enableRemoting(&pingPongServer);

    return app.exec();
}
```

**MyService.java**

```
// java file android/src/com/kdab/training/MyService.java
package com.kdab.training;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

import org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtService;

public class MyService extends QtService
{
    public static void startMyService(Context ctx) {
        ctx.startService(new Intent(ctx, MyService.class));
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.d("MyService", "Called onDestroy");
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public void quit() {
        Log.d("MyService", "Called quit");
        stopSelf();
    }
}
```

If I check the log, the *Called quit* message appears but the *Called onDestroy* never. Do you have any idea why this happens and how can I debug the behavior? Also what could be the reason that my service won't stop? How can I find out what is preventing it from quitting?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

in every service in android can run as a foreground or background. if you want to quit service. you just need to call  `stopSelf();`
the method in onDestroy but you need to make sure that there is no callback happening before calling `stopSelf();`

Answer (score 0):

Call `stopService` with intent will call `onDestroy` method from activity or fragment

```
stopService(Intent(this, MyService.class))
```